# Quotient of zero-dimensional hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I've read (in joy of cats) that every topological space is a regular quotient of a zero-dimensional hausdorff space. So far, I could not find a proof. Do you know one, or a reference?

Comment: For the record: the claim is on p. 215, Example 12.11.

Comment: By a _regular quotient_ you mean regular epimorphism, which is in the category *Top* quotient map?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that by regular quotient you mean existence of regular epimorphism (in **Top**), i.e. of a quotient map. I hope I did not overlook something. (The proof seems to be relatively easy.)

---

Let us say that $X$ is a *prime space* if it has only one non-isolated point.

If $a\in X$, then the *prime factor* $X_a$ of $X$ at $a$ is the space which has the same neighborhoods of $a$ as $X$ and all points other than $a$ are isolated.

It is easy to see that:

- Every topological space is a quotient of a sum of its prime factors.
- A prime factor is either discrete or prime space.

Discrete spaces are obviously zero-dimensional, Hausdorff prime space are zero-dimensional and a sum of Hausdorff zero-dimensional spaces is zero-dimensional. Therefore it is sufficient to show that every prime space can be obtained as a quotient of a sum of Hausdorff zero-dimensional spaces.

Suppose that a prime space $X$ with the accumulation point $a$ is non-Hausdorff. Let $C$ be an intersection of all neighborhoods of $a$. Then the space $X$ can be obtained as a quotient of a sum of:

- the space $X\setminus C\cup\{a\}$  (which is a prime Hausdorff space);
- several copies of [Sierpinski space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space), one for each point of $C\setminus \{a\}$.

Now our problem reduces to obtaining Sierpinski space as a quotient of a Hausdorff prime space, which is easy. (There are many possibilities, e.g. you can obtain is as a quotient of $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n;n\in\mathbb N\}$ with the topology inherited from $\mathbb R$.)

I use the term prime factor and prime space in the same way as in the following papers. (Although I do not claim that Franklin and Rajagopalan were the first ones to use these notions.)

- Franklin S.P., Rajagopalan M., [On subsequential spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641%2890%2990117-K), Topology Appl. 35 (1990), 1--19.
- Zhou J.-Y., [On subspaces of pseudo-radial spaces](http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9303/zhou.pdf), Comment.Math.Univ.Carolinae 34,3 (1993), 583--586